# Angular 2 - Make Sure Calls Come in Order

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, observable

I have this function that gets me the products by page number. Now, sometimes I call this function simultaneously. Like get products by page number 2, 3, 4. Now, sometimes page number 4 is reaching earlier and the order is showing wrong. The question is, How can I make sure the subscribe call is executed in order.

```
GetProducts(PageNumber) {

            this.ProductSubscriber = this.productsService.GetAllProductsByPage(Page).subscribe(products => {

                if (products.length == 0 || products.length < this._AppConfig.PaginationNum) {
                    this.ProductsLoaded = true;
                }
                if (this.products.length != 0) {
                    products.forEach(element => {
                        this.products.push(element);
                    });
                }
                else
                    this.products = products;

            }, err => {

        }
```

Comment: Where/How do you call this method?

Comment: why dont you use a `observable.forkjoin()` i might be wrong here but as you want all the results at same time

Comment: Use `async await` before the calling of method `GetProducts ()`

Comment: I have like infinitescroller, and on scroll down it is calling this function multiple times.

Comment: could you provide a plnkr ? If you have an infinite scroll, you have an event, that call GetProducts with a page number, and then if that one isn't finish you should cancel any other. Your scroll event should work as next button in a pagination. You should be able to call, for instance, the third page if the seconds is not loaded.